# Meteor-roles (alanning). Roles.userIsInRole return false

Tags: meteor, roles, flow-router

I am using the meteor-role package and I have a problem when redirecting on Flowrouter. I have a button in the navbar that redirects the user to home, which is different depending on role. The problem is that the role package take some time to be ready and the error is thrown.
Any ideas on how I could solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
FlowRouter.route( '/', {
  name: 'home',
  triggersEnter: [() => {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'student')) {
        FlowRouter.go('internships_next');
      } else if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'organization')) {
        FlowRouter.go('user_internships');
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error( 500,
          'There was an error processing your request. User id: ' + Meteor.userId()
        );
      }
    }
  }],
  action() {
    mount(LayoutContainer, {
      content: <LoginContainer/>,
    });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that Roles.subscription.ready() is true before redirect:

```
FlowRouter.route( '/', {
  name: 'home',
  action() {
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
      if (Meteor.userId() && Roles.subscription.ready()) {
        if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'student')) {
          FlowRouter.go('internships_next');
        } else if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.userId(), 'organization')) {
          FlowRouter.go('user_internships');
        } else {
          mount(LayoutContainer, {
             content: <LoginContainer/>,
          });
        }
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: By adding Roles.subscription.ready(), the whole if statement is false and the LoginContainer is mounted.

Comment: Update my answer please check.

Comment: it doesn't work. The first if statement is false (because Roles.subscription.ready() returns false), and it shows a blank page as nothing's been mounted.

Comment: Did you wait for a while ?, Because When Meteor.userId() && Roles.subscription.ready() become true, then page will re-rendered.

Comment: That's the problem. The page is never re-rendered. I think that Flowrouter is not reactive and once it gets false it stays false and nothing is updated. So I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: I add Tracker.autorun inside the action now it will be reactive. As per the flow router doc.